# Assigning a return (value) to a new variable

Tags: php

Thanks for all your quick responses! Although the code below looks like I want to print the values to be viewed on-screen I need the values eg. $user_profile [email] in another function (to register new wordpress user). Below is the complete code. How do I do this?

```
<?php
try{
include_once "src/fbaccess.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}
try{
require_once "wp-blog-header.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}

try{
require_once "wp-includes/registration.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Florian's Facebook login</title>    

</head>
<body>
<!-- Copy the below code to display FB Login/Logout button -->
<?php if ($user): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <div>
  <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
<!-- Copy the above code to display FB Login/Logout button -->

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

<?php if ($user): ?>
  <h3>You</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

  <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
   <pre><?php  return ($user_profile [email]); ?></pre>
<pre><?php return ($user_profile [first_name]); ?></pre>
<pre><?php return ($user_profile [last_name]); ?></pre>
<pre><?php return ($user_profile [location]); ?></pre>   
<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: What do you use `return` for? It's likely you misunderstand what it is for.

Comment: I use return in order to get the value of $user_profile [email] so I can use it in another function. I don't want to print the value.

Comment: you still don't understand what it is. See the [documentation](http://php.net/return)

Comment: As the documentation is not accessible right now, maybe you can answer my question?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: If I click on the link it gives me an error.

Comment: search for a tutorial, book, etc.. this is really *basic* stuff.

Comment: Thanks Karoly. What do you think I have been doing for the last day or so? If it is too basic for you, just don't bother answering.

Comment: @Florian Lucke: it's very basic for everyone who can read

Comment: Very helpful, really. Nevermind. And sorry for wasting your precious time.

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to assign it to a variable

`$var = $user_profile['email'];`

but in your example it looks like you want to print it:

`echo $user_profile['email'];`

or with short tags enabled: `<?= $user_profile['email']; ?>`

Comment: I don't want to print the value, instead I need it in another function. I tried $var = $user_profile['email']; and then, just to see if it works, tried to print it via print_r ($var); No success.

Comment: I don't see any function there. Please post the code & the calling code.

Comment: I still don't see a function call. We can't help if we don't know what you're trying to do..

Comment: Code posted. If return (); is the wrong way to get the value for using it in another function, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: I need the values eg. $user_profile [email] in another function (to register new wordpress user) I don't have the function yet, but right now I only want to get the values like $user_profile [email] stored in a variable, so I could use them in the function.

Comment: 1) pass the variable to the function (you know, functions have arguments...) 2) use a global variable

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I think you just want to do the following:

```
if(!empty($user_profile))
{
    <pre><?php echo $user_profile['email']; ?></pre>
    <pre><?php echo $user_profile['first_name']; ?></pre>
    <pre><?php echo $user_profile['last_name']; ?></pre>
    <pre><?php echo $user_profile['location']; ?></pre>   
}
else
{
    <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
}
```

Your code looks like you are trying to echo it out, which will work, but you may also want to use the function `empty()` to check if the variable has anything in it at all.

In regards to return-ing data, this is something that is more commonly associated with functions rather than anything else - which `hsz` has described nicely in another answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

`return` works with functions (or methods inside classes). Proper use looks and assign looks like:

```
function foo() {
  return 'bar';
}

$var = $foo();
```

In your case, returning values to the view (HTML) is pointless. As `Karol Horvath` described, use `echo` instead.